# Laravel Routing fails because of # in variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes

I have a route like this:

```
Route::get('/id/{did}', function ($did) {
    echo $did;
});
```

The variable `$did` contains a serialnumber like this `1705SN#A5F`

When I return `$did` I only get `1705SN`. How can I change this behavior?

I'm running laravel 5.4

Greetings
da.eXecutoR

Comment: urlencode your param

Comment: Use `urlencode()` the problematic string(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you form your url use it like this: `'/id/' . urlencode($did)` so your special character be sent to your server

Answer (score 0):

The data after # (hash) is not sent to server. simple!

if you want # try using its html code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base64_encode at the time of passing "1705SN#A5F" with url. 
Like below

```
<a href="{{url('testnumber/'.base64_encode("1705SN#A5F"))}}">Click</a>
```

And then can decode it like

`Route::get('testnumber/{number}',function ($number){
    $decoded = base64_decode(  $number);
    echo $decoded;
});`